# I'm trying to pluralize words based on a count but my code is not working

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pluralize a noun based on a count and I don't understand what's wrong.

```
// DO NOT CHANGE THE FOLLOWING INPUTS.
const noun = prompt("Enter a noun");
const count = prompt("Enter a number");

console.log(noun);
console.log(count);

// Returns the number and pluralized form, like "5 cats" or "1 dog", given
// a noun and count. Assume there are no irregular plural nouns.

if ((count > 1 ) || (count = 0)) {

  result = count + " " + noun + "s";
}else{

  result = count + " " + noun;
}
// DO NOT CHANGE THIS.
console.log(result);
```

[This is a screenshot of the compiler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XhJ9u.png) .

Comment: Welcome. Please don’t use images for errors or code. Copy them into the question as text instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (comparison)

```js
if ((count > 1 ) || (count == 0)) {
```